# Selenium Webdriver testNG

Tags: selenium, testng

I have created three classes in TestNG and every time that I run my test.xml file it is then opening up multiple instance of IE.

I need to do the the following activity in single browser instance :- Launch IE>>Open URL>>Login To Application>>Search Task.............. As of now by my code it is opening three instance of IE.

**Class FirstClass**

```
package com;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class FirstClass

{
    public static WebDriver driver=null;
  @Test

  public void Login() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:loginName")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:loginName")).sendKeys("nishant");
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:password")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:password")).sendKeys("test1234");
      Select dropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:cabinetMenu")));
      dropdown.selectByVisibleText("neonsit");

      driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:buttonlogin")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5600);


  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {


      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Test\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       driver.get(BaseVariable.baseURL);

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      //driver.quit();
  }

}
```

**Class QuickSearch**

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.BaseVariable;
import com.FirstClass;
import com.Login;
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Const;

public class TestQuickSearch  extends FirstClass {

@Test
public void  QuickSearchByReg_ID () throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginName")).sendKeys("EC*");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("quickSrchProcess")));
    dd.selectByValue("1");
    driver.findElement(By.id("buttonGo")).click();
}


}
```

Comment: Voting to close this because there is no question being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you call the `Class TestQuickSearch extends FirstClass` it initiates the `FirstClass` before `TestQuickSearch` since there is a `@BeforeMethod` and you have two test method (1 test method in each class) the IE browser is initiated twice.

Also show us the TestNG.xml code.

Comment: <suite name="Test - Suite" >
 
 <test name="NeonLogin">
 
 
 <classes>
 <class name="com.FirstClass" />
 
 <class name="com.TestQuickSearch"/>
 </classes>
 
 </test>
 
 </suite>  this is my testng class.........  So Alok can you please tell if i want to do the above functionality at one go Like  :-  Opening browser>>Login to Application>>>then Search the task using TestQucikSearch Class .. what i need to do

Comment: one of the ways would be to have all the methods in 1 class.

Comment: Bring all the methods in one class and then initiate and close the browser using '@BeforeTest' (to open the browser) '@AfterTest' (to close the browser) '@Test(priority = 0)' to Login. '@Test(priority = 1)' to do the quick search.

Comment: Ok.....thanks...  then if i have to do multiple task Like add user/add task etc then i have to create separate class for each and in each class i need to do BeforeTest' (to open the browser) 'AfterTest' (to close the browser) 'Test(priority = 0)' to Login then @test method for work i need to do...Please answer............

Comment: Hi @alok please suggest a better way of doing this

Comment: If u add all the test scenarios in 1 class thn '@BeforeTest' and '@AfterTest' will suffice & u can control d order of d '@Test' method using Priority.
But If u add test scenarios in diff. class then I would suggest make method for opening & closing the browser as '@Test'.
& call the @Test methods in an appropriate sequence using testng.xml
Refer:
[link](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-5-suite-test/)
[link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/multiple-tests-in-testng-xml)
[link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/include-exclude-test-methods-in-testng)

Answer (score 0):

I do not even know what testNG is, but one thing struck me about your post. In your AfterMethod you are not closing IE via a call to driver.quit. You have commented this out. In your BeforeMethod you are opening a new instance of IE.
So it looks like the behavior you describe is expected.

```
@BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {


      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Test\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       driver.get(BaseVariable.baseURL);

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      //driver.quit();
  }
```

On a final point, you didn't actually ask a question. Can you edit your post to actually ask a question?